# Differences between two points

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I'm trying to write a Python function that determines whether or not a couple of geo-points are within 5 meters of distance each other. I have a couple of coordinates like: 13.09073, -86.3560933 and 13.09237, -86.3576067. I tried using a Haversine function but I'm not sure I'm getting the right value.

This is the function so far:

```
from math import sin, cos, pow, atan2, sqrt


def haversine(pos1, pos2):
    lat1 = float(pos1['lat'])
    long1 = float(pos1['long'])
    lat2 = float(pos2['lat'])
    long2 = float(pos2['long'])
    d_lat = (lat2 - lat1)
    d_long = (long2 - long1)

    a = pow(
        sin(d_lat / 2), 2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * pow(sin(d_long / 2), 2)
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
    km = 6367 * c
    print 'km %f' % km
    print 'mts %f' % (km * 1000)


print haversine(
    {'lat': 0.0, 'long': 0.0}, {'lat': 0.0, 'long': 0.0000007852992})
```

That weird number is supposed to be "5 meters" of distance. I remove a conversion feature of degree_to_rad since I think my format is already on radians.

Comment: If you aren't sure you are getting the right value, post examples or code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points)

Comment: oefe, it could be. But I just want to know how much is 5 meters in coordinates, so I want apply conditions based on that value

Comment: What relation is between `13.09073, -86.3560933`, `13.09237, -86.3576067` and `0.0, 0.0` and `0.0, 0.0000007852992` points. What do you want to evaluate?

Comment: No relation, those are samples that I was testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to be able to check against "5 meters in coordinates", because the difference in lat/lon values for points 5m apart is going to vary based on position on the surface of the sphere.

You can try testing your output against values from [an existing script](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). It would not be very usual for lats and lons to be stored in radians, I would definitely check that.

There doesn't seem to be anything amiss with the calculations, but you probably mean to:

```
return km
```

at the end of the `haversine` function, so that `print haversine(...)` actual does something meaningful.

Comment: Which format does Google Maps use for its links?. This is a testing link: https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!1m4!1m3!1d1796!2d-84.0997365!3d9.9330108!2m1!1e3&fid=7. I can see -84.0997365 and 9.9330108. Are they on degrees?

Comment: Those are definitely degrees.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the degree_to_rad conversion back to the function. Thank you!